# How to filter by current month automatically on pivot table google sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, date-range

As a data analyst, I would like to see the report in a pivot table automatically for the current month, so that I can take a look at it and don't have to change the date filter manually.

This is the formula to show the first day of the current month. (Which is the criteria I need, first of the current month)

`=EOMONTH(today(),-1)+1`

It works when I put this formula in any cell.
But when I put it in the pivot "filter by condition" option it doesn't work.

This is what I tried.

1. Text is exactly `=EOMONTH(today(),-1)+1` (In formula box)
2. The date is exactly `=EOMONTH(today(),-1)+1` (In formula box)

Here a screenshot of the options

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try custom formula:

```
=MONTH(A2)=MONTH(TODAY())
```

where A2 is first cell of column containing valid dates

Answer (score 0):

I've never had great luck with the pivot table filter criteria in Sheets, I typically filter the data first if it's more advanced or use aggregating functions. In the Sheets pivot tables are better for quick analysis than dashboards.

There's probably a few ways to do it, but one of the easier ways would be to duplicate the data tab, clear the data and use a filter function to retrieve data. Update the Pivot table data source to the new tab. This will always only be the current month's data.

Basically you filter the data before the pivot table, with the `[filter function][1]`.

> =Filter(data , [date col]>=EOMONTH(today(),-1)+1 ,  [date col]< date(year(today()), month(today())+1,1)

You can also add a month column to the data and then filter on that column, however each month you would need to update the month filter in the pivot table.

> =date(year([date cell]),Month([date cell]),1)

If you're using it for a 'dashboard' of sorts, I would generally recommend to create it yourself with aggregating formulas (sumifs, countifs, ect) and then you can use the more complex filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to *Filter* by a *Custom Formula*:

```
=month(DatePurchase)=month(TODAY())
```

Where `DatePurchase` is the *Field Name*.

Comment: This is identical to @player0's suggestion from nearly six months ago. Before contributing a new answer, please be sure to check the existing answers. Later, once you have more reputation, you'll be able to upvote those answers as a way of validating their guidance.